# FileWriter not receiving all input and mysterious dangling newline issue

Tags: java, io, filereader, filewriter

I am trying to write a Java program in which the user specifies how many "student records" they would like to input, followed by the student's name, age, and GPA, which then gets stored as text. However, I am having a problem with my text not including all entered data and a mysterious dangling newline that I cannot get rid of.
Here is my program:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CreateFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        FileWriter fwriter = new FileWriter("c:\\Students.dat");
        PrintWriter StudentFile = new PrintWriter(fwriter);
        String name = " ";
        String next = " ";
        int age = 0;
        int hm = 0;
        double gpa = 0.0;
        System.out.print("How many student records would you like to enter: ");
        hm = input.nextInt();
        for (int x = 1; x <= hm; x++) {
            System.out.print("Enter Name: ");
            name = input.nextLine();
            input.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Enter Age: ");
            age = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter GPA: ");
            gpa = input.nextDouble();
            next = input.nextLine();
            StudentFile.println(name);
            StudentFile.println(age);
            StudentFile.println(gpa);
        }
        StudentFile.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Here is sample input and output to illustrate my issues:

```
run:
How many student records would you like to enter: 3
Enter Name: Jon
Enter Age: 20
Enter GPA: 3.4
Enter Name: Bill

Enter Age: 24
Enter GPA: 3.6
Enter Name: Ted

Enter Age: 34
Enter GPA: 3.9

This is the produced text file:
20
3.4
Bill
24
3.6
Ted
34
3.9
```

Why doesn't it store the first name entered? Why isn't there a newline in the first entry, but it is in the others?

Answer (score 1):

This is the corrected for loop:

```
for ( int x = 1; x <= hm; x++ )
{
     System.out.print( "Enter Name: " );
     name = input.next();
     input.nextLine();
     System.out.print( "Enter Age: " );
     age = input.nextInt();
     input.nextLine();
     System.out.print( "Enter GPA: " );
     gpa = input.nextDouble();
     next = input.nextLine();
     StudentFile.println( name );
     StudentFile.println( age );
     StudentFile.println( gpa );
}
```

Some things you may want to consider:

- Handle the `IOException` - it should not be ignored!!
- Use the methods `hasNextXXX()` of the `Scanner` to check if something is available.
- Refactor your usage of the variable `next`, it's never really used.
- It's not necessary to call `System.exit( 0 )` from the main method - rather use the `return` statement with a meaningful value.

Comment: Thank you! Would you please explain why this works and why mine doesn't? Why use name = input.next(); instead of input.nextLine();?

Comment: With `nextLine()` after your "Enter Name: " you advanced twice to the next line. But in fact you want to have just the next string, that's why you need to call `next()`. After that you can skip any additional input an advance to the next line, read the integer and so on.

Comment: @MarkusL You should not close the `Scanner`, since it will also close `System.in`, which **you** did not allocate, but the JVM. You should rather add a `@SuppressWarnings("resource")`. I made this mistake too, because the Java compiler gives you a warning, but it does not apply to the `Scanner` as mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that! I removed it from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using `nextLine()` when you need to be using `next()`. I'm assuming you put the second `input.nextLine()` in there because you were initially having a problem where it would print out "Enter Name: " and then immediately "Enter Age: ". `nextLine()` is telling your program to skip whatever is there, and not to wait for it. The reason that this paradigm worked at all for any of your entries is that you put `next = input.nextLine()` at the bottom of your loop. Here's a fix:

```
package createfile;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class CreateFile {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        FileWriter fwriter = new FileWriter("c:Students.dat");
        PrintWriter StudentFile = new PrintWriter(fwriter);
        String name = " ";
        String next = " ";
        int age = 0;
        int hm = 0;
        double gpa = 0.0;
        System.out.print("How many student records would you like to enter: ");
        hm = input.nextInt();
        for (int x = 1; x <= hm; x++) {
            System.out.print("Enter Name: ");
            name = input.next();
            System.out.print("Enter Age: ");
            age = input.nextInt();
            System.out.print("Enter GPA: ");
            gpa = input.nextDouble();
            StudentFile.println(name);
            StudentFile.println(age);
            StudentFile.println(gpa);
        }
        StudentFile.close();
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

You could also just move your `input.nextLine()` above `name=input.nextLine()` and it would have the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

The other examples only work if you don't have names like "James Peter" - in their code examples only James would be saved as name.

I'd prefer this:

```
    System.out.print("How many student records would you like to enter: ");
    hm = input.nextInt();
    input.nextLine();
    for (int x = 1; x <= hm; x++) {
        System.out.print("Enter Name: ");
        name = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter Age: ");
        age = input.nextInt();
        input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter GPA: ");
        gpa = input.nextDouble();
        input.nextLine();
        StudentFile.println(name);
        StudentFile.println(age);
        StudentFile.println(gpa);
    }
```

Comment: How does this work? I tried entering a first and last name, but it did not store them.

Comment: Can you print your in- and output and fileinput in detail? I run the program shown above and all worked the way I've expected it to be.